# Can I obtain Euros anywhere on my walking route from Foca, Bosnia, to Zabljak, Montenegro?

Tags: money, exchange, montenegro, bosnia, euro

I seem to have have messed up in my planning ahead in terms of having Euros for Montenegro. I had wanted to leave Foca in Bosnia today and begin walking towards Zabljak in Montenegro, which is a 90km walk. Unfortunately, there don't seem to be any ATMs nor banks nor currency exchange shops on the Montenegrin side until Zabljak, which is a 90km walk away. On the Bosnian side, I think I might need to go back as far as Sarajevo (where I have walked from) to change currency.

The banks are already closed in Foca unfortunately. In Bosnia, is it possible to obtain euros in a bank? Is it possible for a foreigner to obtain Euros in any other sort of institution or shop in Bosnia (ideally in Foca), for example by paying in Convertible Marks and receiving change in Euros?

I need the money to buy food and for guesthouses.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> In Bosnia, is it possible to obtain euros in a bank?

Yes.  There will be a small fee because the exchange rate is fixed, so the bank cannot make money by buying and selling at different rates.

> Is it possible for a foreigner to obtain Euros in any other sort of institution or shop in Bosnia (ideally in Foca), for example by paying in Convertible Marks and receiving change in Euros?

You might be able to do this, but my guess is that you would receive a pretty bad deal.

Comment: Just to update: I managed to exchange 90 Marks for 45 Euros plus 3 Marks in a supermarket attached to a casual restaurant (the waiter went to ask the cashier for me, and she obliged by opening their store cupboard and secure box for me.) So by luck and kindness of strangers more than anything else. If 45 Euro would be enough for two nights in Montenegro is the next question! (The answer for which I'll be able to easily find on booking.com.)

Comment: @novice I imagine you can change BAM in Montenegro if you need.